# What does "+10% per unused >> Movement" mean?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

In Civilization: Beyond Earth, a number of perks that can be selected when upgrading unit types (e.g. Sentinel, Destroyer, possibly others) read as follows:

```
+10% per unused >>Movement
```

What does this mean? Which stat gains 10%?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there's nothing stated, then it's about damage.

For example, take a look at my Needlejet stats:

[image: Needlejet stats]

It doesn't specifically mention "damage" to keep the lines shorter without omitting any necessary details.

If some upgrade isn't about damage, then it's clearly mentioned. In this example there's the "+1 Range" bonus.

To get back to your actual example:

"+10% per unused >> Movement" essentially means that your unit will do more damage if you attack before moving it. For example, if your unit is able to move 2 tiles (unmodified), then it will do 20% more damage. Move 1 tile first and the bonus drops to 10%.